# Video rate image construction from binary data performance

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, vectorization

**First things first:**

I have a git repo [over here](https://github.com/KrisJanssen/T3Rrender) that holds the code of my current efforts and an [example data set](https://github.com/KrisJanssen/T3Rrender/blob/master/T3Rrender/test.t3r)

**Background**

The example data set holds a bunch of `records` in Int32 format. Each record is composed of several bit fields that basically hold info on `events` where an event is either:

1. The detection of a photon
2. The arrival of a synchronizing signal

Each Int32 record can be treated like following C-style struct:

```
struct {
    unsigned TimeTag    :16;
    unsigned Channel    :12;
    unsigned Route      :2;
    unsigned Valid      :1;
    unsigned Reserved   :1; }  TTTRrecord;
```

1. Whether we are dealing with a photon record or a sync event, time
   tag will always hold the time of the event relative to the start of
   the experiment (macro-time).
2. If a record is a photon, valid == 1. 
   If a record is a sync signal or something else, valid == 0.
3. If a record is a sync signal, `sync type = channel & 7` will give either a value indicating start of frame or end of scan line in a frame.

The last relevant bit of info is that Timetag is 16 bit and thus obviously limited. If the Timetag counter rolls over, the rollover counter is incremented. This rollover (overflow) count can easily be obtained from channel `overflow = Channel & 2048`.

**My Goal**

These records come in from a high speed scanning microscope and I would like to use these records to reconstruct images from the recorded photon data, preferably at 60 FPS.

To do so, I obviously have all the info:

I can look over all available data, find all overflows, which allows me to reconstruct the sequential macro time for each record (photon or sync).

I also know when the frame started and when each line composing the frame ended (and thus also how many lines there are).

Therefore, to reconstruct  a bitmap of size noOfLines * noOfLines I can process the bulk array of records line by line where each time I basically make a "histogram" of the photon events with edges at the time boundary of each pixel in the line.

Put another way, if I know Tstart and Tend of a line, and I know the number of pixels I want to spread my photons over, I can walk through all records of the line and check if the macro time of my photons falls within the time boundary of the current pixel. If so, I add one to the value of that pixel.

This approach works, current code in the repo gives me the image I expect but it is too slow (several tens of ms to calculate a frame).

**What I tried already:**

The magic happens in the function `int[] Renderline` (see repo).

```
public static int[] RenderlineV(int[] someRecords, int pixelduration, int pixelCount)
    {
        // Will hold the pixels obviously
        int[] linePixels = new int[pixelCount];

        // Calculate everything (sync, overflow, ...) from the raw records
        int[] timeTag = someRecords.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x & 65535)).ToArray();
        int[] channel = someRecords.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32((x >> 16) & 4095)).ToArray();
        int[] valid = someRecords.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32((x >> 30) & 1)).ToArray();
        int[] overflow = channel.Select(x => (x & 2048) >> 11).ToArray();
        int[] absTime = new int[overflow.Length];
        absTime[0] = 0;

        Buffer.BlockCopy(overflow, 0, absTime, 4, (overflow.Length - 1) * 4);

        absTime = absTime.Cumsum(0, (prev, next) => prev * 65536 + next).Zip(timeTag, (o, tt) => o + tt).ToArray();

        long lineStartTime = absTime[0];

        int tempIdx = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < linePixels.Length; j++)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = tempIdx; i < someRecords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (valid[i] == 1 && lineStartTime + (j + 1) * pixelduration >= absTime[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }

            }
            // Avoid checking records in the raw data that were already binned to a pixel.
            linePixels[j] = count;
            tempIdx += count;
        }

        return linePixels;
    }
```

Treating photon records in my data set as an array of structs and addressing members of my struct in an iteration was a bad idea. I could increase speed significantly (2X) by dumping all bitfields into an array and addressing these. This version of the render function is already in the repo.

I also realised I could improve the loop speed by making sure I refer to the `.Length` property of the array I am running through as this supposedly eliminates bounds checking.

The major speed loss is in the inner loop of this nested set of loops:

```
for (int j = 0; j < linePixels.Length; j++)
{
      int count = 0;
      lineStartTime += pixelduration;

      for (int i = tempIdx; i < absTime.Length; i++)
      {
          //if (lineStartTime + (j + 1) * pixelduration >= absTime[i] && valid[i] == 1)
          // Seems quicker to calculate the boundary before...
          //if (valid[i] == 1 && lineStartTime >= absTime[i] )
          // Quicker still...
          if (lineStartTime > absTime[i] && valid[i] == 1)
          {
              // Slow... looking into linePixels[] each iteration is a bad idea.
              //linePixels[j]++;
              count++;
          }
      }

      // Doing it here is faster.
      linePixels[j] = count;
      tempIdx += count;
}
```

Rendering 400 lines like this in a for loop takes roughly 150 ms in a VM (I do not have a dedicated Windows machine right now and I run a Mac myself, I know I know...).

I just installed Win10CTP on a 6 core machine and replacing the normal loops by Parallel.For() increases the speed by almost exactly 6X.

Oddly enough, the non-parallel for loop runs almost at the same speed in the VM or the physical 6 core machine...

Regardless, I cannot imagine that this function cannot be made quicker. I would first like to eke out every bit of efficiency from the line render before I start thinking about other things.

> I would like to optimise the function that generates the line to the maximum.

**Outlook**

Until now, my programming dealt with rather trivial things so I lack some experience but things I think I might consider:

1. Matlab is/seems very efficient with vectored operations. Could I achieve similar things in C#, i.e. by using [Microsoft.Bcl.Simd](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/04/22/c-vectorization-microsoft-bcl-simd/)? Is my case suited for something like this? Would I see gains even in my VM or should I definitely move to real HW?
2. Could I gain from pointer arithmetic/unsafe code to run through my arrays?
3. ...

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

I apologize beforehand for the quality of the code in the repo, I am still in the quick and dirty testing stage... Nonetheless, criticism is welcomed if it is constructive :)

**Update**

As some mentioned, absTime is ordered already. Therefore, once a record is hit that is no longer in the current pixel or bin, there is no need to continue the inner loop.

5X speed gain by adding a break...

```
for (int i = tempIdx; i < absTime.Length; i++)
{
    //if (lineStartTime + (j + 1) * pixelduration >= absTime[i] && valid[i] == 1)
    // Seems quicker to calculate the boundary before...
    //if (valid[i] == 1 && lineStartTime >= absTime[i] )
    // Quicker still...
    if (lineStartTime > absTime[i] && valid[i] == 1)
    {
        // Slow... looking into linePixels[] each iteration is a bad idea.
        //linePixels[j]++;
        count++;
     }
     else
     {
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: You *might* get better help over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com.  Though this is not a game, the issues that you are dealing with sound much more similar to their work, than the general issues found on this or most other programming sites in the SE network.

Comment: A couple of - perhaps trivial - hints for `if (lineStartTime > absTime[i] && valid[i] == 1)` -- a) I'm assuming _no_ but if `valid` is mostly false then that check should go first, b) if data happens to be already ordered by absTime, you can avoid that check as soon as it changes between true and false.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's funny you mention that. I indeed played around with the order (valid is mostly true). But in fact, putting the valid check last is systematically faster oddly enough... absTime is indeed "in order" so indeed if I break the inner loop when the comparison is false, I gain a lot of speed... silly I didn't catch that!

Comment: If `absTime` is increasing then you are only counting until it becomes greater than `lineStartTime` - that means that you can break out of the loop as soon as that happens.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError My penny dropped just a fraction of a second too late :) Thanks for that tip, it indeed resulted in a significant gain!